# EKEventKit past date event added in simulator but not on device in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent

I am using `EKEventKit` to add events to calendar. Only today's events are stored on device but not past events. But it is added on simulator.

Following is my code:

```
    func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title:String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate){
        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
         event.title = title

        event.startDate = startDate // contains september 2015 date
        event.endDate = startDate
        event.availability = EKEventAvailability.Free

        event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        do{
            try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
//            JLToast.makeText("Event added successfully").show()
        } catch {

        }

    }
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same problem. The solution was to change a device setting in Settings.app -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Calendars section -> Sync to All Events. Also in my case all the events I tried to create before changing this setting appeared in the Calendar.app afterwards.

I didn't find a way to check this setting from code yet though.